# How can I extract the matches from the Perl match operator into variables?

Tags: perl

If I have a match operator, how do I save the parts of the strings captured in the parentheses in variables instead of using `$1`, `$2`, and so on?

```
... = m/stuff (.*) stuff/;
```

What goes on the left?

Comment: I've completely replaced the question based on joachim's comments to other answers. It's not a regex question.

Comment: With the question phrase like that, it makes sense that you seem to have downvoted my answer.

Comment: @brian, your edit is probably more concise, as my question was purely about the syntax to use with and around the m// operator rather than anything to do with the regexp itself. My bad. But I'd like to put the word 'extract' back in there somewhere, as that's what I'll google for when I forget how to do this!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The trick is to make m// work in list context by using a list assignment:

```
 ($interesting) = $string =~ m/(interesting)/g;
```

This can be neatly extended to grab more things, eg:

```
 ($interesting, $alsogood) = $string =~ m/(interesting) boring (alsogood)/g;
```

Comment: True.
Though the bit I always get stuck on is the syntax to get stuff into named variables, rather than the regexp side of things, so I skimped on the regexp part of the example and answer.

Comment: [Also](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-extract-strings-from-a-file) `@interesting = $string ...`?

Answer (score 9):

Use the bracketing construct `(...)` to create a capture buffer. Then use the special variables `$1`, `$2`, etc to access the captured string.

```
if ( m/(interesting)/ ) {
    my $captured = $1;
}
```

Comment: You **don't need a capturing group** when you want the whole expression. **Just use `$0` instead.**

Comment: @Peter: I think you must have confused $0, the name of the current program, with something else.

Comment: ... with something completely else, in fact.

Comment: the something else being $& (use of which has performance implications to your whole program)

Answer (score 7):

Usually you also want to do a test to make sure the input string matches your regular expression. That way you can also handle error cases.

To extract something interesting you also need to have some way to anchor the bit you're interested in extracting.

So, with your example, this will first make sure the input string matches our expression, and then extract the bit between the two 'boring' bits:

```
$input = "boring interesting boring";
if($input =~ m/boring (.*) boring/) {
    print "The interesting bit is $1\n";
}
else {
    print "Input not correctly formatted\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`@strings` goes on the left and will contain result, then goes your input string `$input_string`. Don't forget flag `g` for matching all substrings.

```
my @strings=$input_string=~m/stuff (.*) stuff/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use named capture buffers:

```
if (/ (?<key> .+? ) \s* : \s* (?<value> .+ ) /x) { 
    $hash{$+{key}} = $+{value};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **$&** - The string matched by the last
>   successful pattern match (not counting
>   any matches hidden within a BLOCK or
>   eval() enclosed by the current BLOCK).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $interesting;
my $string = "boring interesting boring";
$interesting = $& if $string =~ /interesting/;
```

Comment: Don't use $&. Especially in this case, if you are matching literal text, you don't have to match at all. You already know the answer without $&.